# How would I go about Tiling this Basement Bathtub wall?

Tags: tiling

We are wanting tile our bathtub wall with a bond pattern 3x6 subway tile. I am having a hard time planning this out as we have an angled wall near the top of the wall, which is around 5.5" in height. How do I go about laying these out to achieve a decent look?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Decent look is verging on "close as decorating advice" but if you have 3x6 tile and a 5-1/2" angle section, you trim the tiles on both sides to get 2 tiles centered on the section - or you find some tile that happens to be the right size and have an "accent" that's different from the rest of the tile job (some deep dark color, or that tumbled stone stuff, or glass tiles...) offsetting the rest of the stark white tile job.

A section of herringbone seems to be a common "all subway tile" accent technique.